# how can add external php function or class to theme file?

Tags: 8, theming

As I asked above, is it possible to add or include externally written classes or functions files to drupal theme files e.g 'theme_name.theme' file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A .theme file is processed as PHP - anything you can do in a PHP file, you can do in your theme's .theme file.

So if you want a service:

```
$some_service = \Drupal::service('foo');
```

Or a function from a module file:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'foo_module');
```

And so on.

Comment: I would add you can also include namespaced classes via `use`.

Comment: Yeas that is the correct approach to use `use` operator.
eg. use \Drupal as Drupal and do Drupal.service();

Comment: @SwastikPareek That's not the convention Drupal 8 has chosen by the looks of it :) Core contains 5500+ occurrences of `\Drupal::`, and no occurrences of `\Drupal as Drupal` or `Drupal::` without the leading slash